# CustomStringConvertible crashes enum?

Tags: swift

I was playing with `CustomStringConvertible` for my `enum` in XCode playground and I encountered a really strange problem.

See following `enum`:

```swift
enum A {
    case v(UInt8)

    init(val: UInt8) {
        self = .v(val)
    }
}

var a = A(val: 5)
print("\(a)")
```

This code works without any problem and `a` will be equal to `.v(5)`.

After that, I tried to make this class conform to `CustomStringConvertible`. So, I implemented `description` calculated property:

```swift
enum A {
    case v(UInt8)

    init(val: UInt8) {
        self = .v(val)
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}

var a = A(val: 5)
print("\(a) \(a.description)")
```

and still everything works as expected. Then I just added protocol conformance in declaration:

```swift
enum A: CustomStringConvertible {
    case v(UInt8)

    init(val: UInt8) {
        self = .v(val)
    }

    var description: String {
        return "\(self)"
    }
}

var a = A(val: 5)
print("\(a) \(a.description)")
```

Strangely, Now I get segmentation fault. Even though I'm a beginner in swift I find this problem funny and I have never seen that protocol conformace declaration can cause this problem.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you're trying to conform your type to `CustomStringConvertible`? Conformance to `CustomStringConvertible` is useful if you wish to customise the printed representation of your type. However, if you just want Swift's default printed representation, there's no need to conform.

Comment: @Hamish This class shows the simplified version of my class in order to just show my problem. Yes, in my own class, description is more complex, so I wanted to conform to `CustomStringConvertible`. I may drop it if it cause too much confusion though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String interpolation (as in `"\(self)"`) calls the `description` property for values of types which conform to the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol.

Which means that your implementation of `var description` calls itself recursively, which eventually causes a stack overflow and termination of the program.

Comment: oh, got it. So now is there anyway to implement something like what I want to do without a switch/case for all values of enum inside `description` method?

Comment: The only way to prevent this infinite recursion is to provide a `switch` that returns a hard coded name value for each `case`. And yes, this is still needed today, in 2020, even with Xcode 12 and Swift 5.3. This is also mentioned in the Swift forums: https://forums.swift.org/t/use-customdebugstringconvertible-to-produce-enum-case-name-as-string/36298.